# Calculating the JSONPath

Tags: javascript, json, jsonpath

Assuming I have a fairly complex JSON object such as the one below:

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "address": [{
    "streetAddress": "1 street",
    "special": {
      "1 a": "1 b"
    }
  }, {
    "streetAddress": "2 naist street",
    "special": {
      "2 a": "2 b"
    }
  }],
  "phoneNumbers": [{
    "type": "iPhone",
    "number": "0123-4567-8888"
  }]
}
```

Are there any tools/libraries to **calculate the JSONPath to a particular key/value pair**?

For example: the JSONPath to the third row of data (`streetAddress": "1 street"`) can be extracted using the JSONPath `$.address[0].streetAddress`.

Ideally I want something like this: `calculateJSONPath(3)` - where 3 is the 3rd key starting from the top and this function will return `$.address[0].streetAddress`. I don't imagine there'll be something that does exactly this, but I got to start somewhere, if not from scratch.

**Edit: Sample use case:** User loads a JSON file into my application. I allow them to select specific keys using my interface. Imagine checkboxes next to each key. Next the user can upload a second JSON file and see if the previously selected keys/values are present in the second JSON.

**Edit 2:** Searching won't work as I want the key/values selected by the user to be located in the same hierarchy as the first JSON. Eg: If the user selects `"1 a": "1 b"` in the first JSON file, the second JSON file must have the same key/value in the same nested hierarchy.

Comment: What is your use case and what are expected results?

Comment: **Objects** don't necessary respect the order of the keys. So the same call to `calculateJSONPath` can give different results!

Comment: @charlietfl Pls see the edit.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir should be fine if it is a JSON string that is being parsed. Anyways it was just an example, any other method would be fine. What do you recommend?

Comment: It will be better that while generating those checkboxes to store the path to that checkbox in some `data-path` attribute or something, so when the user checks it you can retrieve the path using that attribute.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Yes, that was my plan. However, I am still deciding on the best/easiest way to calculate this path.

Comment: And what about inline JSON?

Comment: Rework both JSON-files into a DOM-structure resembling the JSON-structure and then use `querySelector` to see if the same path can be made. `Object.keys` will be your friend here!

Comment: what about the following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/94xh8Lzn/)

Comment: @gaetanoM thanks, it's a great starting point. There are still some rough edges that I can work out. From the lack of existing solutions I'm guessing there aren't any existing applications that solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a taste of what I said (check an checkbox to see my point):

```js
var $ = {
  "firstName": "John",
  "address": [{
    "streetAddress": "1 street",
    "special": {
      "2 a": "2 a"
    }
  }, {
    "streetAddress": "2 naist street",
    "special": {
      "2 a": "2 a"
    }
  }],
  "phoneNumbers": [{
    "type": "iPhone",
    "number": "0123-4567-8888"
  }]
};


// the recursive function that create the structure
function createStructure(container, obj, path) {
  for(var key in obj) {
    var d = cd(key, path);
    if(typeof obj[key] == "object")
      createStructure(d, obj[key], path + "['" + key + "']");
    container.appendChild(d);
  }
}

// of course we call the function ...
createStructure(document.getElementById("preview"), $, "$");


// create a preview element (unimportant)
function cd(prop, path) {
  var d = document.createElement("div");
  var s = document.createElement("span");

  var i = document.createElement("input");
  i.setAttribute("data-path", path + "['" + prop +"']");
  i.onclick = check;
  i.type = "checkbox";
  s.appendChild(i);
 
  s.appendChild(document.createTextNode(prop));
  d.appendChild(s);
  return d;
}

// the event handler (unimportant)
function check(e) {
  if(e.target.checked)
    alert(e.target.getAttribute("data-path"));
}
```

```css
div {
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="preview">
  <span><input type="checkbox" data-path="$"/>$</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is very nice. Thanks!

Comment: @john You're welcome! But keep in mind this is just a taste. You may want to polish it and add more cool stuff. This was just to give insight and ideas on how to do it.

Comment: Absolutely, this is more than I expected. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The following will create an DOM-structure from the supplied JSON. It's very rudimentary and it's just a proof of concept.

You will need to build the rest of the application from this foundation.

Every level (UL) has an index and every item (LI) a key.

```js
//rework JSON into a structure
function buildDOMFromJSON()
{
  var JSONString = document.querySelector("#uploadedJSON1").value;
  
  //you need to add a gazillion error checks
  var JSONcompiled = JSON.parse(JSONString);

  //test if array or object
  var start, isObject;
  if (JSONcompiled instanceof Array)
  {
      start = JSONcompiled;
      isObject = false;
  }
  else //is object
  {
     start = Object.keys(JSONcompiled); //create an array to start
     isObject = JSONcompiled;
  }
  
  loopJSONLevel(start, isObject, document.querySelector("#JSONstructure1 > ul"));
}

function loopJSONLevel(obj, isObject, level)
{
  //loop the array
  obj.forEach(function(element, index){
    var objectToEvaluate;
    if (isObject == false)
    {
      objectToEvaluate = element; 
    }
    else
    {
      objectToEvaluate = isObject[element];
    }

    //create a new level
    var newLevel = document.createElement("li");
    var newLevel2 = document.createElement("ul");
    if (objectToEvaluate instanceof Array)
    {
      //create a new level
      if (element instanceof Array)
      {
          newLevel2.setAttribute("data-path", index);
      }
      else
      {
          newLevel2.setAttribute("data-path", element);
      }      
      level.appendChild(newLevel2);
      loopJSONLevel(objectToEvaluate, false, newLevel2);
    }
    else if (Object.prototype.toString.call(objectToEvaluate) == "[object Object]")
    {
      //create a new level
      if (element instanceof Array)
      {
          newLevel2.setAttribute("data-path", index);
      }
      else
      {
          newLevel2.setAttribute("data-path", element);
      }
      newLevel2.setAttribute("data-path", index);
      level.appendChild(newLevel2);
      loopJSONLevel(Object.keys(objectToEvaluate), objectToEvaluate, newLevel2);
    }
    else
    {
      //draw the value
      level.appendChild(newLevel);
      newLevel.textContent = objectToEvaluate;
      newLevel.setAttribute("data-path", element);
    }
    
    
  });
}
buildDOMFromJSON()
```

```html
<textarea id="uploadedJSON1">
  [{
  "firstName": "John",
  "address": [{
    "streetAddress": "1 street",
    "special": {
      "1 a": "1 b"
    }
  }, {
    "streetAddress": "2 naist street",
    "special": {
      "2 a": "2 b"
    }
  }],
  "phoneNumbers": [{
    "type": "iPhone",
    "number": "0123-4567-8888"
  }]
}]
  </textarea>

<div id="JSONstructure1">
  <ul>

  </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same thing using Angular.

You can see an example below :

https://davicvictor.github.io/jsonpath-ui/ and open your console.

Comment: Welcome to SO! While the contents of the link you provided might answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer in your post and provide the link for reference, since link only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.